# User's email update time Send an email for authentication in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, updates

When the user registers, an email will be sent to confirmation

But how do I send a notification when a user updates their email?

Like when he registers

Comment: where do you want to notif the user, to the old email or new email?

Comment: Here are lots of ways to do it, please google it you will find out, you can set observer or you can send it on the update time.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reverify your user's email  , you should set his email_verified_at to null then call sendEmailVerificationNotification method .

in your user model (located in app\user) add this method :

```
 public function sendNewVerification() {
    $this->email_verified_at =null; 
   $this->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
 }
```

and call it in your controller .

hope that would work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... but how do I call it in my controller?

Comment: it depends on where you put this action  . for example if your controller's method it's called update use this there . 
also i can help you more if you attach a screen shot of your controller and method that you are working on .